# Helpful suggestions for bash backup script for samba shares using rsync

Tags: bash, backup, rsync, samba

I have written a small bash (4) script to backup shares from my windows pc's. Currently I backup only one share and the backup is only visible to root. Please give me some hints for improvements of that piece of code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to back up directories on several windows machines
# Permissions, owners, etc. are preserved (-av option)
# Only differences are submitted
# Execute this script from where you want

# Make sure only root can run our script
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

# Specify the current date for the log-file name
current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S)

# Specify the path to a list of file patterns not included in backup
script_path=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
rsync_excludes=$script_path/rsync_exclude.patterns

# Specify mount/rsync options
credential_file="/root/.smbcredentials"
# Specify windows shares
smb_shares=( //192.168.0.100/myFiles )
# Specify the last path component of the directory name to backup shares 
# content into
smb_share_ids=( "blacksmith" )
# Specify with trailing '/' to transfer only the dir content
rsync_src="/mnt/smb_backup_mount_point/"
rsync_dst_root=(~/BACKUPS)

# Check if all arrays have the same size
if [ "${#smb_shares[@]}" -ne "${#smb_share_ids[@]}" ]; then
  echo "Please specify one id for each samba share!"
  exit 1
fi

# Run foor loop to sync all specified shares
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#smb_shares[@]} ; i++ ))
do
  # Check if mount point already exists
  echo -n "Checking if mount point exists ... "
  if [ -d $rsync_src ]; then
    echo "Exists, exit!"
    exit 1
  else
    echo "No, create it"
    mkdir $rsync_src
  fi

  # Try to mount share and perform rsync in case of success
  echo -n "Try to mount ${smb_shares[$i]} to $rsync_src ... "
  mount -t cifs ${smb_shares[$i]} $rsync_src -o credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=0,file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0600
  if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "Success"

    # Specify the log-file name
    rsync_logfile="$rsync_dst_root/BUP_${smb_share_ids[$i]}_$current_date.log"

    # Build rsync destination root
    rsync_dst=( $rsync_dst_root"/"${smb_share_ids[$i]} )

    # Check if rsync destination root already exists
    echo -n "Check if rsync destination root already exists ... "
    if [ -d $rsync_dst ]; then
      echo "Exists"
    else
      echo "Does not exist, create it"
      mkdir -p $rsync_dst
    fi

    # Run rsync process
    # -av                   > archieve (preserve owner, permissions, etc.) and verbosity
    # --stats               > print a set of statistics showing the effectiveness of the rsync algorithm for your files
    # --bwlimit=KBPS        > transfer rate limit - 0 defines no limit
    # --progress            > show progress
    # --delete              > delete files in $DEST that have been deletet in $SOURCE
    # --delete-after        > delete files at the end of the file transfer on the receiving machine
    # --delete-excluded     > delete excluded files in $DEST
    # --modify-window       > files differ first after this modification time
    # --log-file            > save log file
    # --exclude-from        > exclude everything from within an exclude file
    rsync -av --stats --bwlimit=0 --progress --delete --delete-after --delete-excluded --modify-window=2 --log-file=$rsync_logfile --exclude-from=$rsync_excludes $rsync_src $rsync_dst
  fi

  # Unmount samba share
  echo -n "Unmount $rsync_src ... "
  umount $rsync_src
  [ "$?" -eq "0" ] && echo "Success"

  # Delete mount point
  echo -n "Delete $rsync_src ... "
  rmdir $rsync_src
  [ "$?" -eq "0" ] && echo "Success"


done
```

Now I need some help concerning following topics:

1. Checking if conditions like share existence, mount point existence (to make a fool proof script)
2. The mount command - is it correct, do I give the correct permissions?
3. Is there a better place for the backup files than the home directory of a user if only root can see that files?
4. Do you think it would be helpful to integrate the backup of other file systems too?
5. The backup is rather slow (around 13mb/s) although I have a gigabit network system - possibly this is because of the ssh encryption of rsync? The linux system, where the share is mounted on, has a pci sata controller and an old mainboard, 1gb ram and an athlon xp 2400+. Could there be other reasons for the slowness?

If you have more topics that can be addressed here - be welcome to post them. I'm interested =)

Cheers

-Blackjacx

Answer (score 0):

1) There is a lot of error checking you can do to make this script more robust: check for existance and execute status of external executables (rsync, id, date, dirname, etc.), check the output of rsync (with if [ 0 -ne $?]; then), ping the remote machine to make sure it is on the network, check to make sure thet user you are doing the backup for has a home directory on the local machine, check to make sure the destination directory has enough space for the rsync, etc.

2) mount command looks ok, did you want to try to mount as read only?

3) Depends on the number of users and the size of the backup. For small backups the home directory is likely ok, but if the backups are large, especialy if you might run out of disk space, a dedicated backup location would be nice.

4) Depends on what the purpose of the backup is. In my experience there are five kinds of things that people backup: user data, system data, user configurations, system configurations, entire disks or filesystems. Is there a seperate system task that backs-up the system data and configurations?

5) What other tasks are running while the backup takes place? If the backup is running automated at say 1 AM, there may be other system intensive tasks scheduled for the same time. What is your typical throughput rate for other kinds of data?

You are performing an array check on non-array variables.

Use a variable to specify the remote machine.

```
# Remote machine
declare remote_machine="192.168.0.100"
# Specify windows shares array
declare -a smb_shares=([0]="//$remote_machine/myFiles"
                       [1]="//$remote_machine/otherFiles" ) 
# Specify the last path component of the directory name to backup shares  
# content into 
declare -a smb_share_ids=( [1]="blacksmith" [2]="tanner")
```

that way you can

```
ping -c 1 $remote_machine
if [ 0 -ne $? ] ; then
   echo "ping on $remote_machine Failed, exiting..."
   exit 1
fi
```

If rsync_src is only used for this mackup, you might wat to try

```
mnt_dir="/mnt"
rsync_src=`mktemp -d -p $mnt_dir`
```

and I would make this dir before the for loop otherwise you are creating and destroying it for every directory you back up.